# ¿Por qué "if[$variablecontrol - eq 1];" no funciona?

Tags: bash, condiciones, shell, shell-script

Estoy desarrollando un *script* en Bash en el que quiero que la ejecución de un bucle se realice cada vez que pulsamos la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

El programa ejecuta una vez su bucle principal, y al llegar al final pide  al usuario que pulse <kbd>Enter</kbd> para continuar ejecutando el bucle principal.

El código resumido sería el siguiente:

```
variablecontrol=0
for ((i=0 ; i< 10; i++){
  variablecontrol=0
  acciones
  if[$variablecontrol - eq 1]; then
    printf "Introduce Enter para continuar"
    read -p " "
  fi
}
```

Si quito el `if` funciona perfectamente, ya que para cada ejecución me pide introducir un <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Pero cuando pongo el `read` dentro del `if`, siempre me ejecuta todo de vez sin pedir un <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

He hecho `prints` de la variable de control antes de llegar al bucle y si que llega en ocasiones con valor `1`, pero en ningún momento pide el salto de linea.

¿Qué esta fallando?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El comando `test` es un poco estricto en su formato.

esta parte:

```
  if[$variablecontrol - eq 1]; then
  # ^^                     ^^
    printf "Introduce Enter para continuar"
    read -p " "
  fi
```

puede ser ignorada. La forma correcta deberia ser con espacios entre los elementos internos:

```
  if [ $variablecontrol - eq 1 ]; then
  #  ^^^                      ^^
    printf "Introduce Enter para continuar"
    read -p " "
  fi
```

nota que hay un espacio en blanco entre el `if`, el `[` y el `$` al principio, y entre el `1` y el `]` al final

referencia: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Por otra parte, ten cuidado. si `$variablecontrol` no esta definida antes de llegar al if, entonces el comando queda:

```
if [ -eq 1 ]; then
```

lo cual se puede interpretar como un error de codigo. Por tanto, como mínimo deberías entrecomillar la variable y decir: `if [ "$variablecontrol" - eq 1 ];`.

Answer (score 3):

Antes de ir al tema principal sobre el *built-in* `[` tengo que hacer énfasis en decir que en `bash` , el ciclo `for` no empieza ni termina entre llaves `{}`. Sino que empieza y termina entre los *tokens* `do` y `done` seguidos de un punto y coma o un salto de línea.

Ahora, volviendo al tema de tu código en la sintaxis de `[`, el *built-in* `[` es un alias al *built-in* `test` de bash, por lo que su uso lo puedes ver al escribir `help [` y `help test`.

Como `[` tiene un significado especial, recuerda que las palabras se definen en relación a algo que indique que son palabras, es decir, un separador, o un IFS. Por lo que no es lo mismo escribir `if[condicional` que `if [ condicional` ya que en el segundo caso, por el espacio como separador, se entiende la diferencia entre estos tres componentes, `if`, `[` y los comandos condicionales.

Dicho esto, tu script podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((variablecontrol=10 ; variablecontrol > 0; variablecontrol--))
do
  acciones
  if [ $variablecontrol -eq 1 ]; then
    read -p "Introduce Enter para continuar"
  fi
done
```

Esto además de que, tal vez por copiar y pegar, escribiste como condicional

```
$variablecontrol - eq 1
```

con el guión separado del *token* `eq` cuando tiene que ir junto, debido a que el *built-in* `[` es un operador binario y unario, no ternario. Entonces, al escribir `[ $variablecontrol - eq 1 ]` tienes 4 tokens y ninguno de ellos guarda relación entre si. El primer error que arrojaría la consola es el de `[: too many arguments`. Entonces, con `[ $variablecontrol -eq 1 ]`, es decir, sin el espacio entre el guion `-` y el token `eq` ya se vuelve algo binario, es decir, operas sobre dos elementos, `$variablecontrol` y `1` con el operador `-eq`.