# ¿Cómo usar el condicional if en Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejemplo sencillo de un condicional "if" en Bash bajo un Linux Debian 9.

Sin embargo, me marca `no found`

```
#!/bin/sh

cadena="hola"

if [$cadena == "hola"]; then 
    echo "good" 
else 
    echo "bad" 
fi
```

El error que me da:

```
$ chmod +x prueba.sh
$ sh prueba.sh 
prueba.sh: 5: prueba.sh: [hola: not found
bad
```

incluso cambié la expresión `==` por `-eq` pero me marca los mismo `not found`.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Comando read en Bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270403/comando-read-en-bash)

Comment: @Marco si propones duplicado surgiero que lo hagas a preguntas cuyo título sea relevante. Si no, difícilmente servirán para encontrar soluciones

Comment: Es que el problema de esa pregunta es que es el error sobre el built-in `[` pero el que preguntó lo hizo con un título erróneo.

Answer (score 3):

El operador `[` necesita estar rodeado de espacios. Por tanto, en lugar de:

```
if [$cadena == "hola"]; then 
#   ^
```

Debes escribir:

```
if [ $cadena == "hola" ]; then 
#   ^                 ^
```

Al fin y al cabo `[` es un operador como cualquier otro y para ser reconocido no debe tener caracteres a su alrededor. Si no, ocurre lo que indica tu error: `[$cadena` se interpreta como `[hola` al expandir la variable y efectivamente `[hola` no es ningún comando.

Comment: copie el codigo bueno que escribiste pero ahora me marca esto                   $ sh prueba.sh 
prueba.sh: 5: [: missing ]
bad

Comment: Ah bueno claro porque debe haber espacio en el otro lado. Edito

Comment: Es porque también tiene que terminar con un espacio y luego el caracter `]`. Todo se separa con espacios.

Comment: Me sigue marcando error  [: hola: unexpected operator

Comment: @gokuvenz ¿Aún con el espacio entre el "hola" y el token `]`?

Comment: si aun con el espacio entre el "hola" y el token

Comment: @goku nótese que no estás usando Bash sino sh. (/bin/sh). No sé si es lo que pretendes, pero es importante la diferencia.

Answer (score -3):

Esto funciono para mi, las expresiones deben de estar juntas

malo

```
$cadena == "hola"
```

bueno

```
$cadena=="hola"
```

agregar espacio en el operador `[`  `]`

al final queda de la siguienta manera

```
if [ $cadena=="hola" ]; then
```

Comment: Eso es lo que te indiqué en mi respuesta. En lugar de volver a decirlo, lo usual es aceptar la respuesta que te explicó.

Comment: Ademas, parece que no entendiste. No hay nada malo en `$cadena == "hola"`, eso funciona perfectamente. Es el `[` y el `]` que tienen que ser rodeados de espacios: `[ $cadena == "hola" ]`.

Comment: Porque aceptar una respuesta incompleta????, la respuesta de fedorqui me manda error  " [: hola: unexpected operator"  eso no me sirve asi

Comment: El error "unexpected operator" te sale porque estás ejecutando Sh, no Bash. Lánzalo como `bash prueba.sh`.